# How do I add a quadratic constraint using coeff in the scipsuite python interface

Tags: python, scip

How do I add a quadratic constraint using the scip python interface?
In one of the examples, I see something like model.addCons(`x*x+y*y<=6`)
However, since I have a lot of variables(x1..xn and my constraint is of the form `x'Qx<=0.2`, where x is n*1 and Q is n*n), this method is rather impossible. How can I put the quadratic constraint in a python dictionary of coeffs as I do the linear constraints? `(coeffs={x**2:3.0，y**2:1.0,z**2:5.0}` for example if I want `3x^2+y^2+5z^2<=10`)

Comment: How does `{x:3, y:1, z:5}` relate to 10?

Comment: the 10 is not important just putting here as an example, 10 will be put into the constraint later by setting lhs.

Comment: but how is that calculated from 3,1, and 5?  3+1+5=9 so I'm trying to figure out where the 10 came from.

Comment: the 3 and 1 and 5 are the coefficients of the variables x^2, y^2, z^2

Comment: oh sorry I thought you wanted to generate the restriction based on the dict.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported. You need to loop through your quadratic constraints and add them one after the other using the expression method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But since I have a large number of quadratic terms in my constraint (x'Qx, where Q is of the scale 5000*5000). Can I efficiently loop through this large number of terms?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't. This largely depends on how your coefficients are stored. When creating the quadratic constraint, though, I highly recommend using the quicksum() method instead of explicitly stating the linear or quadratic expression.

Comment: How can I use the quicksum() method, is there any document about it,thanks

Comment: It's similar to Gurobi's implementation: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/refman/py_quicksum.html

Comment: Example: ```model.addCons(quicksum(c[i,j]*x[i,j] for i in I for j in J) <= 10)```

Comment: ...and you need to import it:  ```from pyscipopt import quicksum```